# How to create outlook task request in java

Tags: java

I would like to know how to create outlook "Task Request" in java.

Comment: Your question is too vague. What do you want to achieve exactly, and what did you already tried?

Comment: I want create task request in my outlook using java code. I ahve gone through the site Java Outlook Connector. But couldn't find anything specific to "How to create task request"

Comment: Recommend you flesh out the question (even if it's copying the guesses from your answerer below...) so it doesn't get closed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another Java lib: http://moonrug.com/

Answer (score 0):

I have used an earlier version of this API in my previous job. It is a commercial product.

Trying to code purely from memory and looking at the examples provided by the Moyosoft website. I have no means to compile or execute this. But you will get an idea on how to proceed

```
 Outlook outlookApplication = new Outlook();

 // Get the Task folder where the task has to be created
 OutlookFolder taskFolder= outlookApplication.getDefaultFolder(FolderType.TASKS);

 //Creating a new Task
 OutlookTask task = new OutlookTask (taskFolder);

 task.setSubject("New Java Task"); //Name of the Task
 task.setStart(new Date()); // creating task with current server time
 task.setStatus(TaskStatus.NOT_STARTED); //task has not yet started
 task.setOwner("owner's_email@example.com"); // I don't whether this is name or email.
 task.setReminderTime(new Date()) //set a reminder time, set appropriately
 task.setDueDate(new Date()); //deadline for the task completion, set appropriately

 // and so one.
```

The following APIs should help you.
http://www.moyosoft.com/joc/javadocplus/?docclass=com.moyosoft.connector.ms.outlook.task.OutlookTaskRequest

http://www.moyosoft.com/joc/javadocplus/?docclass=com.moyosoft.connector.ms.outlook.task.OutlookTask

The complete java docs can be found here. It is not very well documented but the API names are self explanatory. 
http://www.moyosoft.com/joc/javadocplus/

Their site also have a few code examples which was helpful in figuring it out.
I hope this is helpful. I do not have access to these APIs now, therefore I have no way to provide code examples.

Comment: Thanks for your reply kensen.
I found some code examples on this site. But none of the example is there for OutlookTaskRequest. I am struggling to find but nothing has been found yet.
Please help me to get the code example for moyosoft OutlookTaskRequest

Comment: @Mama I can give it a shot (editing my answer, added code there), but i have no means to compile or test it. But you will get the idea. It has been a long time back and I do not have access the api's.
You wont be able to execute/compile the code without the Moyosoft api.

Comment: Thanks for your great support kensen.
I have tried your code. It is working very fine. 
Now, the only problem is it is not setting the receiver mail address in To box.
task.setOwner("owner's_email@example.com"); - is not setting into the To box.
I have no idea the purpose of setOwner.